# Set TextBlock Visibility based on a bound bool

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to link the visibility of a TextBlock to a bool property which is also linked to a checkbox using WPF and c#. I have the following code in two different sections of the same xaml file (one section is a summary, and the other is settings. I am very new to WPF, and am learning as I go. Currently, the TextBlock is visible no matter what the value of IsSecondaryMessageFilePath is.

```
<TextBlock Name="secondaryfolderinfo" Foreground="Red">
    <ContentControl Content="Secondary message folder" Foreground ="Black" />                    
    <ContentControl Content = "{Binding Path=SecondaryMessageFilePath}" ContentStringFormat="" ClipToBounds="False"></ContentControl>
    <ContentControl Content = "   "></ContentControl>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSecondaryMessageFilePath}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Further down I have:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSecondaryMessageFilePath, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Name="SecondaryPathCheckBox"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="320,7,0,0">Save additional locations</CheckBox>
```

Finally, in the code-behind, I have:

```
public bool IsSecondaryMessageFilePath
{
    get { return _isSecondaryMessageFilePath; }
    set
    {
        if (_isSecondaryMessageFilePath != value)
        {
            _isSecondaryMessageFilePath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsSecondaryMessageFilePath");
        }
    }
}
private bool _isSecondaryMessageFilePath;

public string SecondaryMessageFilePath
{
    get { return _secondaryMessageFilePath; }
    set
    {
        if (_secondaryMessageFilePath != value)
        {
            _secondaryMessageFilePath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SecondaryMessageFilePath");
        }
    }
}
private string _secondaryMessageFilePath;
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Working from the suggestion below, I tried adding the BooleanToVisibilityConverter, but am getting a missing assembly reference for it, and am to new to WPF to figure out how to resolve it. My opening code is as follows:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="Sender_Receiver.SenderReceiverSetup"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:diagnostics="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
    xmlns:m=...
    xmlns:

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibiltyConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks ok at first glance, but you really don't need to use a data trigger for this. WPF comes with a BooleanToVisibilityConverter class that you declare in your resources:

```
<BooleanToVisibiltyConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
```

Then in your TextBlock, you bind Visibility:

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Path=IsSecondaryMessageFilePath, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Just so you know, there may be a simpler way to do this, just bind to the IsChecked property itself!

```
<CheckBox x:Name="UseSecondaryPath"/>
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding ElementName=UseSecondaryPath, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Of course if you need the bool for something else that wouldn't be an ideal solution, but it is a little cleaner if its just for the UI.

The code for a custom BooleanToVisibilityConverter, if you are interested, is:

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert (object value, ...)
   {
       if ((bool)value)
          return Visibility.Visible;
       else
          return Visibility.Collapsed;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, ...)
   {
      return Binding.DoNothing;
   }
}
```

Let me know if I can clarify anything or assist further.

Comment: Thank you for your response. As I said, I know hardly nothing about WPF, so am probably making an obvious mistake here, but I added the BooleanToVisibilityConverter, but I am told that I am missing an assembly. I looked it up, and see that this is located in System.Windows.Controls, but I'm not quite sure how to add this schema. I tried adding xmlns:b="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls", but that didn't work. I posted the code above.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add a namespace for System.Windows.Controls. Did you try building? The XAML parser is notoriously bad at warning for thing like converters until you actually build. If you don't have it for some reason (.NET version?), I can post the code for it, its a really simple converter :)

Comment: I tried rebuilding, and get the error, "The tab 'BooleanToVisibilityCoverter' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'.

Comment: Your class name is misspelled (missing the last 'i'), sorry I missed that earlier.

Comment: I also added the code for your own version of this converter, you could try that if you still can't use Microsofts.

Comment: It has been a long time since I've made a mistake like that. I was too busy worrying that I didn't know what I was doing with WPF to notice the obvious error. I have the code in place now, but unfortunately, the visibility is still not being controlled by the checkbox. With WPF, it is difficult to debug, since you cannot seem to break the code, and even Debug.WriteLines don't seem to get triggered for some reason. I was attempting to see if the property was being updated, but have not been too successful.

Comment: You'll know if the property is updated by just setting a breakpoint in the setter of the bound property, does that get hit? Also, the "ElementName" version should always work, so you could narrow down the source of the problem by trying that.

Comment: Actually, when running WPF, breakpoints in my code do not get hit. I don't know if this is a setting I have wrong in VS 2010, although I have looked through my settings, and everything looks good.

Comment: You should definitely be able to hit breakpoints. Not having them will definitely make debugging hard :(. Mine work fine (granted I'm in VS2012) but it sounds like *something* is wrong with your IDE setup. Sorry I can't be of more help with that issue.

Comment: I was looking through the code and realized that the UI is executed from another application, which is why the breakpoints and Debug lines are not working. I can work around this with a little popup window. Not an ideal solution, but quick and dirty.

Comment: Assuming you have the source to the external app, I've gotten debugging working in that scenario by just attaching to the external application. It even opens up the "plugin" source code! That last bit might be VS2012 though...

Comment: I once again looked at my code from a debugging standpoint rather than a "this is new to me and I must be doing something wrong" standpoint, and found where I had made the error. Everything is working now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
private Boolean _IsChecked;
//Bind this to your checkbox
public Boolean IsChecked
{
    get { return _IsChecked; }
    set { _IsChecked= value; OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked"); OnPropertyChanged("TextBoxVis"); }
}


//Bind this to your TextBox's Visibility Property
public Visibility TextBoxVis
{
    get { return IsChecked ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed; }
}
```

Comment: Technically, this would work. However, this is really what a converter is for.

Comment: @LordTakkera not technically. This really will work and is a viable solution. Converters are more efficient when you are taking values out of a database like 1 , 2 , 3 and you want to convert them to a value like Green, Pineapple and Web. You see code like this all the time.